# Как получить Device ID передающийся в андроид маркет?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Вопросы по андроиду.

1. Как получить Device ID передающийся в андроид маркет?  Вот программа показывающая правильный id `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redphx.deviceid` . Хочу написать аналог, но к сожалению получаю не тот id. Пробовал `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId();` и `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);` все не то. Где прячется этот ID?
2. Как получать информацию о точках доступа wifi каждую секунду? Нужно запускать таймер или это делается через специальную функцию?

UPD. Первый пункт сдался. Оказалось нужно было влезть в настройки маркета на телефоне.
UPD2. Проект с решением первого вопроса можно скачать тут svn://svn.loglist.org:2402/usr/svn/opensource/android/DeviceInfo. Один java файл: http://pastebin.com/HBdMb0jZ Смотреть, где выводится Account и Market ID, с 77 строчки.

Comment: @mikelsv если вы решили вопрос по-поводу DeviceId - то надо поделиться с народом. Запостите ответ на свой вопрос!

Comment: Запостил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Может что-то полезное найдете тут: [android-market-api-php](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api-php/wiki/HowToGetDeviceID).
И тут: [Is there a unique Android device ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id).

По поводу вайфая, думаю, будет сервис, который проверяет по [public List getScanResults ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getScanResults())  результаты.